# Getting coordinates from a touch panel with I2C

Tags: arduino-mega

Hello world (this is my first message in this forum).

I am quite a just-married-to-Arduino guy, I am very passionate about this platform that I kew since long time but never had the time to dedicate.

Now I have done several home projects that made me both feel happy and feel sooooo rookie... But hey, here I am trying more and more complex things.

I am trying to do something I haven't found information about: I have a 10" touch panel (I am not talking about a screen, just the touch surface) which is a capacitive 10 pin panel that communicates with I2C protocol (there are SCL and SDK pins). I have managed to scan the address and turns out it is in the #40.

However, other than that I do not have the knowledge to get the coordinates out of that panel. My question is: is there any library that can help me with that or will I need to code everything?

I am attaching some pictures of the panel and the pinout to have a clearer picture of what I am talking about.

I thank you all for your time reading my post, I hope some day I will be able to provide some answers rather than questioning!

Joan.
[image: touch pannel]

[image: panel pinout]

[image: Controller]

Comment: Have you googled for a datasheet of that chip?

Comment: Where did you get that panel? Don't they provide any identification or information? A datasheet is necessary to do anything with the panel (at least, when you cannot sniff on a working communication with it, when it is connected to a working master device)

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your comment. I have googled it and found nothing really interesting. The user hcheung found an interesting library, but I have hit a rock with a part of the code I can't deal with (look below). The panel came to me by somebody that purchased it on ebay, so not really easy to get the source... I have found the manufacturer of the chip though: FocalTech

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple [library](https://github.com/hellange/arduino/tree/master/capacitive_7in_panel) that works for FT5xx6 display panel.

**Other information available:**

Application node - https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/FT6x06_AN_public_ver0.1.3.pdf

Datasheet - https://www.newhavendisplay.com/appnotes/datasheets/touchpanel/FT5x26.pdf

In case those links might be no longer available in the future, a quick search on FocalTech FT5xx6 should give you the relevant information.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your help! I have started with the library and have come out with an issue when trying to compile. I am afraid I am very novice if I don't know where the problem is, but the error is in this line: FT5xx6 cmt = FT5xx6(CTP_INT);

Comment: It seems that you are trying to create an instance of FT5xx6 class, the line `FT5xx6 cmt = FT500x(CTP_INT);` is simply incorrect. If you want to create an instance called `cmd`, it should be `FT5xx6 cmd(CTP_INT);`.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your comment. I tried your suggestion and it shows the exact same error. Maybe there is something wrong in the libraries? I had to make the library file myself copying the text from the Github repository, maybe I did something wrong...

Comment: Ah, I just realised that the github is not structured as a proper Arduino library that you could download and use it. You need to do it manually. 1) Go to your Libraries directory where your Arduino IDE located, create a directory called FT5xx6; 2) copy FT5006.cpp from the github and save it inside the directory you just created, do the same for FT5xx6.h; 3) create a new project from Arduino IDE, and copy the example code from capacitive_7in_panel.ino on github. It should works now. I just tried (compilation only, didn't run as I don't have a FT5xx6 module). Good luck.

Comment: Hi again. I believe that is what I did, however I couldn't copy the file, but copy the text and generate a plain text file as it is not downloadable. I did this from a MAC computer, I will try to do it with a PC... Is this how you did it? Or there should be a way I could download the files?

Comment: Yahoo! It works. MAC or something was making these files go wrong for some reason. I made all the process on a PC and turns out that I get data. Now the difficult thing will be to understand it. I would like to make it just give me a set of coordinates of a single touch, it looks like this script delivers a lot more information than that. I am only interested in a single point touch, now I need to understand all the data in the serial monitor and figure out which is good for me. I will post an image of what I get. Thanks for your help! It is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi hcheung, I have been struggling with the code and the panel, but something is wrong... the monitor shows weird data, like I am touching 15 points or even touching in the same spot gives different data every time. Until it looks like something "saturates" and starts giving coordinates of 4095x 4095y. I really am lost now. Do you have any idea why this happens? I think I will start a new thread with the exact issue. Thanks for your help!